# Vuejs - How to submit only the visible elements in a single form (with Vuelidate)

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate, formvalidation.io

I have a form which includes some hidden and visible elements inside of it and I want to submit some of the elements without validating the hidden ones. At the top of my form there are three radio buttons and they control my form elements. When `radiobutton1` selected, some of my form elements become visible and when another radio button is selected, there are some other form elements are visible and some of them are hidden. My question is how am I going to submit my form elements if only they are visible? All of the inputs should be in a single form so I am not allowed to separate them into different forms or different components. What I need to do is when I click the `submit` button of my form, the form should only submit the visible elements, and it shouldn't send me any error because I left some of the inputs empty (the hidden ones).

I also use Vuedalite so I couldn't figure out how to handle this problem. All of the input fields in the form has the `required` rule but this rule should be active `ONLY IF THEY ARE VISIBLE.`

Here is a little code.

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <!-- Content Section -->
        <div v-show="showContent">
          <!-- Name Field-->
          <div>
            <div>
              <label>Name</label>
              <input v-model="name" :class="{'is-invalid' : $v.networkname2GHz.$error }" type="text"/>
              <small class="errorMessage" v-if="!$v.name.required && $v.name.$dirty">Name field is required.</small>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Surname -->
        <!-- Content Section -->
        <div v-show="showContent">
          <!-- Surname Field-->
          <div>
            <div>
              <label>Surname </label>
              <input v-model="surname" :class="{'is-invalid' : $v.surname.$error }" type="text"/>
              <small class="errorMessage" v-if="!$v.surname.required && $v.surname.$dirty">Surnamefield is required.</small>
            </div>
          </div>
    <div show="showContent">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I want to do is when the user selects the `Name radio button` only the Name field of the form will be visible and Surname will be hidden, I've done that, no problem. But how do I submit only the name field when surname still empty and has the required rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-if` instead of `v-show`.
The main difference between the two is that, v-if - Only renders the element to the DOM if the expression passes. v-show - Renders all elements to the DOM and then uses the CSS display property to hide elements if the expression fails.

Comment: The problem is not showing or hiding elements. The problem is submitting only the visible ones and not having error.

Comment: If you are using `v-if` it will submit only visible ones. I updated my answer so that you can get some clue.

Comment: So if i put my conditions into v-if statements like v-if="selected==radiobutton1" etc, it will only render the selected items to the DOM so that I can submit only the visible elements right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Will you tick my answer if it works?

Comment: I put my v-if statements in every form element and now they are all in a single form and when I select radiobutton1 it shows only two input elements and when I select radiobutton2 it displays the other ones and hides the first two inputs. I tried to submit the form when radiobutton1 is selected (all of the others are hidden with v-if) and it sends me the error because the hidden ones were empty. I put required rule with Vuelidate so it still sends "This field is required" error.

Comment: You need to apply different validation rules depending on `showContent`.

Comment: I did that too. v-if="selectedRadio=== 'radiobutton1" or v-if="selectedRadio=== 'radiobutton2". Every form element has these v-if statements. 

 <small class="errorMessage" v-if="!$v.username.required && $v.username.$dirty">Secondary Username field is required.</small> also every form element has these error messages...

Comment: I edited the error messages for every element as follows; <small class="errorMessage" v-if="selectedRadio=== 'radiobutton1' && !$v.username.required && $v.username.$dirty">Username field is required.</small> it still tries to submit every element in the form wther they are visible or hidden. I select radiobutton1 and only the first two elements are displaying, I try to submit them and it gives me error because the hidden ones are empty, it sends the "this field is required" error. So it still tries to submit every element and sends error because they are empty.